# Cassandra DB misunderstanding partition key and primary key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Good Evening,

my problem is, that my recent understanding for partition and primary key is, that the partition key is to distribute the data between the nodes, and the primary ALWAYS contains the partition key. I want to create a partition key to cluster the data with duplicate partition keys and in these clusters I want to have a primary key for unique rows. In my first understanding of Cassandra, it could be possible if can take apart the partition and primary key. Is this possible?

An example to ease my idea:

| country | state | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | TEXAS | 123 |
| USA | TEXAS | 114 |

country and state as the partition key and the unique id as the primary key.
If I create the primary key like this: PRIMARY KEY ((country, state,unique_id)) I can't filter without using the unique_id but I want e.g. a query like SELECT unique_id FROM table WHERE state = 'Texas' and country = 'USA'.
If I create the primary key in this way: PRIMARY KEY ((country, state)), it obviously overwrites the data every time one entry gets inserted with the same country and state that's why I need the unique primary key.

Comment: The answer by @alex-ott  is totally correct. From my side, I'd suggest you to take Cassandra course (developer path) at academy.datastax.com, it's free. Running Cassandra without proper training is a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, @alex-ott was right! Sorry, but I don't like the way you are advertising the company you work for. Already watched a lot of videos and read as well on data-stax about partition and primary keys. Running it in a small private program to get familiar with it, I think that's not a bad idea :P!

Comment: That's a bit funny @Nue

The "company I work for" wrote at least 50% of all Cassandra source code. You work with C* using Java, Python, NodeJS, C# or C++? You use a driver written by the "company I work for". You attend an online or in-person C* event? Most of them hosted be the "company I work for".

So yes, I do advertise the course we did, the high-quality free course that helped *literally* thousands of developers and administrators to get proper training helping them to dodge big issues on their prods, free of charge. That's one of the best things the "company I work for" ever did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary key always includes the partition key, that's always a *first item* in the primary key. Partition key could consist out of multiple columns, that's why you have brackets around first item in your example.  I believe that in your case, primary key should be as following:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((country, state),unique_id)
```

In this case, partition key is a combination of country + state, and then inside that partition you will have unique IDs that will be used to select specific items.  General syntax for primary key is:

```
partition key, clustering column1, clustering column2, ...
```

where partition key could be either:

- `column` - single column
- `(column1, column2, ...)` - multiple columns

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, tried this approach already and it didn't work maybe I had something else a wrong this point!

Comment: Please look for comment about DataStax academy - it's a great source of information. Or take "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide, 3rd edition"